# How to open an executable file in the browser using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, browser

I am creating a ReactJS admin dashboard, and I want a button that will open an executable program from the client machine browser on windows. Is there a way that I can do this?

I have currently no progress in doing this. Is this possible to do?

Comment: What does "opening an exe" mean?

Comment: Why do you want to open an executable file right in client browsers? Note that opening one and running one on the operating system are two different things.

Comment: I just want to make it easier to run the executable file on the clients machine. So that the client don't have to manually find the exe file on the file folders.

Comment: That is a bad idea. There are so many things to consider, especially security wise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.